# Is it possible to calculate non-resonant Raman coefficient in Quantum ESPRESSO for systems that require smearing to converge?

Tags: quantum-espresso

In Quantum ESPRESSO turning **lraman** to *true* in the **ph.x** input is not possible if the material is made to converge using **smearing**. Is there any way to circumvent this, as my material isn't a metallic a system, and increasing the **ecutwfc** , **ecutrho** or **k-pioints** doesnt help ?

Comment: Can you converge the calculation by first converging the calculation using smearing, and then using the resulting wavefunction as an initial guess of a calculation that does not use smearing?

Comment: @wzkchem5 I tried like you said by setting startingwfc='file' but it still gave me a "charge is wrong" error.

Comment: Hi Ashique, have you had any luck with this since asking the question? Any updates?

Comment: @NikeDattani Nope! I don't know if it's an inherent limitation to DFT, but currently, I don't believe it's possible to do the above given using Quantum espresso.

Comment: How did this go? Have you found an answer now? It would be nice to get this out of the unanswered queue since it's been there for more than 12 months now! Please update us!  Is the answer simply "no it can't be done using Quantum ESPRESSO?"

Comment: If your system is not metallic, then what do you mean by saying that it "requires smearing to converge"? What is the Kohn-Sham gap of the system, and what role does smearing play in your calculation?

Comment: @leopold.talirz My system was actually a doped semiconductor. Even though there is gap, as far as my experience, doped system usually needed smearing to converge. Otherwise the convergence ends up being too slow.

Comment: @leopold.talirz did that last comment help? Do you think you can write an answer? Now this is in the top 35 oldest questions that have gone unanswered!